# Scrolling on safari, Jquery dialog not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Whenever I click on an div container a Jquery dialogs opens. Everything works smooth expect for the safari browser. For some weird reason when I scroll down it bugs and I dont know what i'm doing wrong.

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

video of the issue: https://streamable.com/89k8b

Jquery dialog:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".dialog").dialog("option", "position", {my: "center", at: "center", of: window});
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $( ".dialog" ).dialog({ dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog', autoOpen:false});
    });

    var opt = {
    autoOpen: false, 
    closeText: '<?php echo $lang["23"]; ?>',
    width: 950,
    height: 600,
    title: null,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true, 
    create: function (event) { $(event.target).parent().css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'z-index': '10', 'top': '50%', 'margin-top': '-350px', 'left': '50%;', 'margin-left': '-1000px' }); },
    buttons:
        [
              {
              text: "<?php echo $lang["44"]; ?>",
              click: function() 
              {
                 $('.dialog').dialog('close');
              }
          }
        ]  
}

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.dialog').dialog(opt);
})
```

html:

```
   <div onclick="$('#dialog-<?php echo $hotel['ms_id']; ?
   >').dialog('open').dialog(opt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
position: 'fixed'
```

to

```
position: 'absolute'
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Hey, this did you help me solving this problem.

Nothing different happend